# Filter Firebase analytics events based on user properties in Google Data Studio

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics, looker-studio

Using BigQuery it is possible to connect Firebase analytics to Data Studio.
Data source can be either the "EVENTS" or the "USER PROPERTIES".

My problem is that I want to filter the events based on user properties, but I can't have both of them in the same data source.

Update:
Here is an screenshot which shows my dashboard.
As you can see when adding a data source which is a Firebase analytics report, after selecting the table, you have to select "EVENTS" or "USER PROPERTIES".
[image: events or user properties]

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can use an arbitrary query in Data Studio to connect to BigQuery. You can find many examples that combine BigQuery and Firebase on StackOverflow, as well as in the help articles for those two products.

Comment: what do you mean by "I can't have both of them in the same data source"?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard I tried to add datasets using a custom query, but the problem is that it will not handle the data the way that it is being handled when Data Studio detects Firebase analytics. Data Studio parse the report and shows user friendly fields and handles filters when it detects Firebase Analytics. (Checkout the Firebase logo next to the table name in my screenshot)

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Check out the screenshot in the question please.

Comment: It still sounds like you should just come up with a custom query then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you're doing, it sounds like you just need to select `Custom Query` under `BigQuery` in the `Connectors` list from Data Studio. Then you can write whatever arbitrary query that you want instead of reading from a single table, which is what will happen if you select `My Projects`, `Shared Projects`, or `Public Samples` from the list instead.